# How to modify the following jQuery code so it applies to each li element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$ul = $('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item > ul');
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item > ul').remove();
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item').wrapInner('<span>');
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item').append($ul);
```

Which basically turns sometimes like this:

```
<li>
  <a></a>
  (10)
  <ul></ul>
</li>
```

into this:

```
<li>
  <span>
    <a></a>
    (10)
  </span>
  <ul></ul>
</li>
```

The problem is that the page has many `<li></li>`.

How to do it so the code is only applied to each `li` without interfering with the rest?

Comment: Have you tried $.each function? I think it may help here.

Comment: @Mayur Tendulkar where to put `$.each`?

Comment: $('li').each(function() { /* your append function */ }); within $(document).ready()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) lets you iterate over each of the selected elements and then you can apply the operation to each of them:

```
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeName !== 'UL';
    }).wrapAll('<span />');
});
```

With proper use of jQuery methods, you can also save some explicitly DOM manipulations.

Comment: +1. Much better than my (deleted) answer, where I used `.wrapAll()` but still had the `.remove()` and `.append()` for the ul.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks, the code is shorter, but the text node `(10)` wasn't wrapped int he `<span>`.

Comment: @alexchenco: Sure? It should be :-/ **edit:** indeed, such a pity.

Comment: @FelixKling Here is the live site with the code: http://lovetaipei.com.tw/business-directory/ "custom.js"

Comment: @FelixKling is `contents` excluding text nodes?

Comment: @alexchenco: Fixed. No, the problem was that `.not` also discards text notes (it only considers element nodes). Using a custom filter function works, but is not as pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the `li` elements and perform the individual changes relative to the current element:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).clone(true),
    ul = content.children('ul').remove();

    $(this).html($('<span />').append(content.contents()).append(ul));        
});
```

**Update:** adapting my answer to the edited code:

```
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $ul = $this.children("ul");
    $this.children("ul").remove()
    $this.wrapInner('<span>')
    $this.append(#ul);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code. So I have to do something like this? `$(this).children("ul")`?

Comment: @alexchenco that's right! I've also updated the answer to correspond to the changed question code.

Comment: Sorry, I can only check one answer.